# ALIGN_PARENT_TOP programmatically not working

Tags: android

Why this isn't working?

```
for (PlayingCard playingCard : Stack0.Cards)
{
    ImageView myImg = new ImageView(this);
    myImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.c2);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(CardWidth, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0,0);
    //lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP); fails
    //lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP); fails
    //lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_START); fails
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);
    myImg.setLayoutParams(lp);
    mat.addView(myImg);
}
```

the xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/PLAY_Mat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    >
</RelativeLayout>
```

The ImageView is successfully being added, but it's centered **vertically**. I want it to align to **top**. 
I expect this to be the way even without the added rule, as "By default, all child views are drawn at the top-left of the layout" (RelativeLayout documentation).

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
 RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);

 for (PlayingCard playingCard : Stack0.Cards)
    {
        ImageView myImg = new ImageView(this);
        myImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.c2);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        lay.setMargins(0, 0, 0,0);
        lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

        rl.addView(myImg, lay);
        //myImg.setLayoutParams(lp);
        //mat.addView(myImg);
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Image is centered vertically. I did change 2 things; 1) width of image is 150 which I've set, as the native size is larger than that (I need to scale it down). 2) you added the image to rl. I added it to mat (my reference to the desired parent viewgroup).

Comment: This actually works, but only if I use the image's native size (WRAP_CONTENT). If I use a pixel value the image is again centered. Unfortunately the size/scale of my image varies based on conditions.

Comment: Your suggestions helped solve the issue. Please see my OP. The addRule isn't needed, and my OP specified a set width rather than wrap_content. Thanks

Comment: if the suggestion helped...mark it as correct..thnkx

Comment: I've marked it as useful, but it feels misleading to call it a correct answer. Your answer doesn't work if a width in pixels is specified, as per my op, and ALIGN_PARENT_TOP isn't needed (as it's the default). I do thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

set **MATCH_PARENT** to `RelativeLayout`

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(CardWidth, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

or

You can get using **getLayoutParams()** of `RelativeLayout` from `XML`

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = parentRelativeImageview.getLayoutParams();
```

Comment: have you tried `RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP` instead of  `START`

Comment: Tried that (add rule ALIGN_PARENT_TOP), also doesn't work.

Comment: remove `lp.setMargins(playingCard.UI_MarginLeft, playingCard.UI_MarginTop, 0,0);` and secode thing above code's behavior also depends on other code so please post all code

Comment: I've added more code, and edited a bit. The left and top margins are both 0.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

This code works:

```
    for (PlayingCard playingCard : Stack0.Cards)
    {
        ImageView myImg = new ImageView(this);
        myImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.a1);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(CardWidth, CardHeight);
        lay.setMargins(playingCard.UI_MarginLeft, playingCard.UI_MarginTop, 0, 0);

        mat.addView(myImg, lay);
    }
```

The key here is CardWidth and CardHeight are both set, and both correct. By correct, I mean correct ratios. Want to double the width? Then double the height etc. If one of w or h is a pixel int, and the other WRAP_CONTENT, then weirdness happens (in the form of the image having either a top margin or a left margin). 
Once both w and h are set correctly, `lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START)` isn't needed.